# Python openCV: Cannot show an image

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I'm using python opencv and I'm trying to import an image and show it but I get the following error:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, fi
le C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\highgui\src\
window.cpp, line 271
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\high
gui\src\window.cpp:271: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like image is corrupted. Did you try to open it in another app (some viewer for example)?

Comment: @kvorobiev Yes. I've uploaded the image if you want to test it.

Comment: Try to execute type(img) after img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0) and post result

Comment: @kvorobiev This is the result: `<type 'NoneType'>`

Comment: The problem in reading of jpeg file, not in imshow

Comment: @kvorobiev Which is the proper way to read it?

Comment: You use proper way. Looks like this is installation problems (with jpeg library). Try to reinstall opencv and carefully read all error/warning messages.

Comment: @kvorobiev OK, thank you for your help and your time! Really appreciate it!

Comment: @kvorobiev Windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [1]: a = None
In [2]: type(a)
Out[2]: NoneType
In [3]: import cv2
In [4]: img = cv2.imread('messi.jpg',0)
In [5]: type(img)
Out[5]: numpy.ndarray
In [6]: img = cv2.imread('messii.jpg',0)
In [7]: type(img)
Out[7]: NoneType
```

Here your type of `img` is NoneType. So,It's problem with the miss spell or not existing of the image. Please check the spelling or existing of file.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure your image file paths and img_names(existed) should be corrects as well as imread()  object results shouldn't be nonetype and then

```
cv2.imshow('image', img)  
cv2.waitkey(0)
```

then your image can display